# getting certificate Error while accessing server

Tags: ibm-domino

[image]

When a new user tried to access his mail file he is getting the error message as shown in above picture. What could be the possible reason for the error? I Googled but didn't find a exact reason for this. Can anyone help me to understand this?

> The certificate table does not contain enough valid certificates to
>   verify the public key of its owner. Do you want to access the server?"

Comment: How is the user accessing the Lotus Domino server, via Lotus Notes client (which version) or via browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this problem once when the client ID accessing the server having the same certifier names, but different origins, e.g. /acme and /ACME. Both Certificates have the same name but different public keys.

I don't think you could create a cross-certification to solve this problem.